# how to open a pdf in tab using aspose C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, aspose

How to load a pdf from desktop to tab control using Aspose.pdf package?
I donot see any document load functions in the package. I am new to this.
I am using a tab control in a C# form to load the document and then search for words inside the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Pdf is an API. Unfortunately, it does not have any UI control which you can place in tab or any other WinForms control.

One solution could be to convert each page to image and show the images in control.

But, if you want to search and highlight text within control and want the text and other objects selectable and scrollable, just like Adobe does, wait for any other member to suggest an alternate.

I work for Aspose as Developer Evangelist.